# How to update listView of FragmentPage from MainActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

In My apps, I've created a Tabbed Activity that consists of 2 tab. What I'm doing is, adding new data to my database from the toolbar menu.
What i want to know is how to update the listView that were located on my First fragment Page. 
In my first fragment page I already have a method called `performServerQuery()` which reset the adapter and populate my adapter with new Data.
What i can think of is to call the `performServerQuery()` from my mainActivity, but it says fail to invoke method adapter.clear() on a null object reference.
Is there any other way to refresh the ListView from my fragment page directly from my mainactivity?

Edit : there are so many same questions on stackoverflow, most of them are by using broadcast. Can I do it without sending broadcast?

Comment: OnTabSelectedListener to onPageSelected method call to set viewpager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: what do you mean by "OnTabSelectedListener to onPageSelected method"? Sorry I'm new to android

Comment: Are you change tab this time not updating your data right?

Comment: Are you using any adapter?

Comment: yes, I'm using custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

**Add this line in your customAdapter**

```
 public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

**And add addOnPageChangeListener**
Look like this

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            vpFrames.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```